# How to make this code work with onBlur mode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, onblur

My code works with 'Onclick'. I need it to work with onBlur mode in JavaScript.

**My code**

```
if(!m.isSystemButtonClicked)
{
  console.debug("Inside onHide. m.isSystemButtonClicked=",m.isSystemButtonClicked);
  if(m.unloadListener)
  {
    window.onbeforeunload = m.unloadListener;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### onblur Event syntax

**In HTML:**

```
<element onblur="myScript">
```

**In JavaScript:**

```
object.onblur=function(){myScript};
```

**In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:**

```
object.addEventListener("blur", myScript);
```

**example :**
<sub><sup>[source - http://www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)</sup></sub>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>When you enter the input field (child of FORM), a function is triggered which sets the background color to yellow. When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which removes the background color.</p>

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="myInput">
</form>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
x.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction, true);
x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction, true);

function myFocusFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";  
}

function myBlurFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your example can be rewritten as

```
m.onblur =  function() {
 console.debug("Inside onHide. m.isSystemButtonClicked=",m.isSystemButtonClicked);
 if(m.unloadListener)
 {
    window.onbeforeunload = m.unloadListener;
 }
}
```